# How to incorporate SSML into Python

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I need to use SSML to play an audio file with the  tag in my Alexa Skill (as per Amazon's instructions).

Problem is, I don't know how to use SSML with Python. I know I can use it with Java but I want to build my skills with Python. I've looked all over, but haven't found any working examples of SSML in a Python script/program - does anyone know?

Answer (score 5):

This was asked two years ago but maybe someone will benefit from the below.

I've just checked and if you use [Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Python](https://github.com/alexa-labs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python) you can simply add SSML to your response, for example:

```
@sb.request_handler(can_handle_func=is_request_type("LaunchRequest"))
def launch_request_handler(handler_input):

    speech_text = "Wait for it 3 seconds<break time="3s"/> Buuuu!"

    return handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).response
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

SSML audio resides in the `response.outputSpeech.ssml` attribute. Here is an
example obj with other required parameters removed:

```
{
 "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak>
              Welcome to Car-Fu.
              <audio src="https://carfu.com/audio/carfu-welcome.mp3" />
              You can order a ride, or request a fare estimate. Which will it be?
              </speak>"
    }
}
```

Further reference:

- [JSON Interface Reference for Custom Skills](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference#Response%20Format)
- [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference#audio)

Answer (score 3):

Install ssml-builder "pip install ssml-builder", and use it:

```
from ssml_builder.core import Speech

speech = Speech()
speech.add_text('sample text')
ssml = speech.speak()
print(ssml)
```

Answer (score 2):

These comments really helped a lot in figuring out how to make SSML works using the ask-sdk-python. Instead of

```
speech_text = "Wait for it 3 seconds<break time="3s"/> Buuuu!" - from wmatt's comment
```

I defined variables that represents the start and end of every tags that I'm using

```
ssml_start = '<speak>'
speech_text = ssml_start + whispered_s + "Here are the latest alerts from MMDA" + whispered_e
```

using single quotes and concatenate those strings to the speech output and it worked! Thanks a lot guys! I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This question was somewhat vague, however I did manage to figure out how to incorporate SSML into a Python script. Here's a snippet that plays some audio:

```
  if 'Item' in intent['slots']:
    chosen_item = intent['slots']['Item']['value']
    session_attributes = create_attributes(chosen_item)

    speech_output =  '<speak> Here is something to play' + \
    chosen_item + \
    '<audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/example/example.mp3" /> </speak>'
```

Comment: User BMW has pointed out the correct answer. When you set the `type` param of the `outputSpeech` JSON object to `SSML` and use `ssml` instead if `text`, you can use SSML tags (as documented in the [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference)).

Answer (score 1):

The ssml package for python exists.

you can install like below by pip

```
    $ pip install pyssml
    or
    $ pip3 install pyssml
```

so example is link below

http://blog.naver.com/chandong83/221145083125
sorry. it is korean.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # for amazon
    import re
    import os
    import sys
    import time
    from boto3 import client
    from botocore.exceptions import BotoCoreError, ClientError
    import vlc
    from pyssml.PySSML import PySSML


    # amazon service fuction
    # if isSSML is True, SSML format
    # else Text format
    def aws_polly(text, isSSML = False):
        voiceid = 'Joanna'

        try:
            polly = client("polly", region_name="ap-northeast-2")

            if isSSML:
                textType = 'ssml'
            else:
                textType = 'text'

            response = polly.synthesize_speech(
                    TextType=textType,
                    Text=text,
                    OutputFormat="mp3",
                    VoiceId=voiceid)

            # get Audio Stream (mp3 format)
            stream = response.get("AudioStream")

            # save the audio Stream File
            with open('aws_test_tts.mp3', 'wb') as f:
                data = stream.read()
                f.write(data)


            # VLC play audio
            # non block
            p = vlc.MediaPlayer('./aws_test_tts.mp3')
            p.play()

        except ( BotoCoreError, ClientError) as err:
            print(str(err))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        # normal pyssml
        #s = PySSML()

        # amazon speech ssml
        s = AmazonSpeech()

        # normal 
        s.say('i am normal')

        #  speed is very slow
        s.prosody({'rate':"x-slow"}, 'i am very slow')

        #  volume is very loud
        s.prosody({'volume':'x-loud'}, 'my voice is very loud')

        #  take a one sec
        s.pause('1s')

        #  pitch is very high
        s.prosody({'pitch':'x-high'}, 'my tone is very high')

        # amazone 
        s.whisper('i am whispering')
        # print to convert to ssml format
        print(s.ssml())

        # request aws polly and play
        aws_polly(s.ssml(), True)

        # Wait while playback.
        time.sleep(50)
```